# Cmake in Visual Studio Code found no kits

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Cmake in vs code did not show any kit although I had install MinGW c++, Cmake and added them all to PATH.
Can anyone explain for me? Thank you in advance.
[Cmake in vscode Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCP4a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happen when the file
`C:\Users\&{YOURNAME}\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json`
has wrong json format

Comment: You should also provide a solution with your answer; what is the proper json format to add? Can you add an example?